# Program to overlay one particular window

Tags: windows

I'm fairly new to programming and I need to create a program that would overlay my browser window (not just the whole desktop), and make it at least be able to hide when the browser window is minimized/switched from. Its contents will be just a couple buttons and some text. What programming language is capable of something like that?

Comment: When in doubt which programming language is capable, the answer is machine language of the machine you're using, always. If you then modify your question to which higher language is capable, the answer is assembly. Then again replaying the ping-pong question-answer game, the answer is C. Now and then again, choose a language first and post your code you're running into a programming problem with.

Comment: And with little programming and as it's Windows, the answer could be Autohotkey (AHK), but I have no idea if that little gem it is still available.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.